# Project compiles but doesnt seem to build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, build

I have a solution with several projects.
The projects have references to each other lie project A uses project B and so on (no circular reference, of course)

Problem is that when I make a change to one of the projects and hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to debug and run my main web application,it is not built and the app runs. If I have a break point on it for example, the break point shows a message

"The breakpoint will not currently be hit. The source is different from the original version"

to solve that, I have to right click the project, choose "clean", do the same on the solution,  rebuild the project and then rebuild the solution. I mean, it is a lot of trouble.

Would anyone know why this is happening and how to prevent it? How to make the project completely build with <kbd>F5</kbd> only?

Comment: If it compiles then it has to build.  Your question makes no sense. You need to set the active project to the project that has depdencies on all the other projects.

Comment: what makes no sense is your comment. Maybe the title is not the best but if you read the question you will understand what's happening. The project build and run but it doesn't seem to see the changes I made to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked in the build "Configuration Manager" to ensure that the projects are "ticked" for building?

[image: Configuration Manager]

Answer (score 1):

Check that your project is set to be built for the configuration you're using.

Right click on the Solution and go to Configuration Manager. Ensure that your project is selected under the 'Build' column.